# Dynamically display a single row of a custom list

Tags: web-part, custom-list

In SharePoint 2010, I have created a custom list and I want to be able to display a single row of this custom list on page. But I do not want to create a separate page for each row.

I would like to be able to pass a url parameter with the row id or something.

for example:

I would have one page called rowview.aspx

where `http://mysite.com/rowview.aspx?id=1`
would show all the information in row 1

And `http://mysite.com/rowview.aspx?id=2`
would show all the information in row 2

Is this possible (and easy) in SharePoint 2010? 
or would I need to write a custom web part or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is possible with out of the box web parts. You can leverage data view web part to display items from your custom list and query string filter web part to send filter values to the data view webpart. Check out a nice series of articles here: http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157%2D7d96%2D4e15%2Da987%2D54b8a3e4d948&ID=77

I think the 3rd article in the series is what you need.

Comment: oh awesome thanks. The third one was almost exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: the provided link is a dead link